# Unable to add default constructor on class that implements Runnable

Tags: android, default-constructor

This message is being displayed when i try to generate a signed apk

> Error in surfaceView implements Runnable class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)"

and yet surfaceView implements Runnable does not support a default constructor... when I  I try to put a default constructor an  error comes again

> the class doesn't allow a default constructor

what else could be done to solve this problem?

Here is my code

```
  public class view extends SurfaceView implements    
  Runnable {

volatile boolean playing;
private Thread gameThread = null;
private king myKing;
private Paint paint;
private Canvas canvas;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private lebel myLebel;
private fire myFire;
private worldking peace;
int screenX;
int countCollisions;

boolean flag ;
int i;
private boolean isGameOver ;
private boolean congrats;
int score;
int highScore[] = new int[4];
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

 public view(Context context, int screenX, int screenY) {
    super(context);
    myKing = new king(context, screenX, screenY);
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    paint = new Paint();
    myLebel = new lebel(context, screenX, screenY);
    myFire = new fire(context);
    peace = new worldking(context, screenX, screenY);
    this.screenX = screenX;
    countCollisions = 0;
    isGameOver = false;
    congrats= false;
    score = 0;
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
    while (playing) {
        update();
        draw();
        control();
    }
  }


   private void update() {
    score++;
    myKing.update();
    myFire.setX(-250);
    myFire.setY(-250);
    if (myLebel.getX() == screenX) {
        flag = true;
    }
    myLebel.update(myKing.getSpeed());
    if (Rect.intersects(myKing.getDetectCollision(), 
     myLebel.getDetectCollision())) {
        myFire.setX(myLebel.getX());
        myFire.setY(myLebel.getY());
        myLebel.setX(-200);
    }
        peace.update(myKing.getSpeed());
        if (Rect.intersects(myKing.getDetectCollision(), 
      peace.getDetectCollision())) {

            myFire.setX(peace.getX());
            myFire.setY(peace.getY());
            playing = false;
            isGameOver = true;
            myLebel.setX(-200);
        }
     }
    private void draw() {

     if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(30);
        paint.setColor(WHITE);
        canvas.drawText("SCORE:"+score,100,50,paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(
                myKing.getBitmap(),
                myKing.getX(),
                myKing.getY(),
                paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(
                    myLebel.getBitmap(),
                    myLebel.getX(),
                    myLebel.getY(),
                    paint
            );
        canvas.drawBitmap(
                myFire.getBitmap(),
                myFire.getX(),
                myFire.getY(),
                paint
        );
        canvas.drawBitmap(

                peace.getBitmap(),
                peace.getX(),
                peace.getY(),
                paint
        );
        if(isGameOver){
            paint.setTextSize(100);
            paint.setColor(WHITE);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            int yPos=(int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - 
        ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2));
            canvas.drawText("Oops! Try 
          Again !",canvas.getWidth()/2,yPos,paint);
        }
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
    }

   private void control() {
    try {
        gameThread.sleep(17);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

   public void pause() {
    playing = false;
    try {
        gameThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    }

    public void resume() {
    playing = true;
    gameThread = new Thread(this);
    gameThread.start();
    }
```

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory: just add a default empty constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but if I add a default empty constructor another error emerges. " The class with surfaceView implements Runnable doesn't support an empty default constructor" I've already explained that in my question. The debuggers tells you to remove the detault empty  constructor uve already added.

Comment: Adding the logcat to your question would help a lot.

Comment: android {
        lintOptions {
         checkReleaseBuilds false
          found:
          abortOnError false
          }
         }

Comment: I added that on the build script and it worked.. thanks for your answers Rotwang. I really appreciate

Comment: Feel free to answer your own questions below